# Rails Engine gem using another Rails engine gem from git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

Rails 4 @ Ruby 2

So i have two engine (A, B) gems that cannot be uploaded to Rubgems because the code is private, so im using git.

A must use B, so basically i should add B as a dependency in A gemspec. As far as i know, gemspec doesn't allow git based gems as a dependency inside gemspec.

I tried to use A gemfile but no luck. Is there a way out?

Comment: take a look at gemfury.com, it is like rubygems but for private gems, it is compatible with .gemspec

Comment: what did you exactly try with the Gemfile? I think if you include gem B into the Gemfile of gem A, it should work correctly. Don´t forget to run the bundle install command before you build your gem A. The dependencies should be in the Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 3):

For development or test, you can do it in Gemfile. You can even point it to use your local folder.

```
gem 'gem_b', path: "/path/to/the/folder"
```

or to use a git reference

```
gem 'gem_b', git: "git@github.com:user/gem_b.git"
```

This will allow you to do the development and testing.

Another option is this. If you have 2 engines, I assume you also have a Rails app to use them. In that rails app, you can simply require them in Gemfile one after another using git reference.

```
gem 'gem_b', git: "git@github.com:user/gem_b.git"
gem 'gem_a', git: "git@github.com:user/gem_a.git"
```

If you must declare this dependency in gemspec, you can build the gem using rake;

```
cd /path/to/gem_b
rake build
```

This will create a `gem_b.gem` file under `pgk` folder.

Then you can install it in your local using gem instal like this

```
gem install pgk/gem_b.gem
```

Now you have gem_b installed in our local. There will be no problem adding it as a dependency in gemspec.

When you are ready to release your application, you need to copy gem_b.gem to your server and install using usual way;

```
gem install /full/path/to/gem_b.gem
```